# SQL Server : using column values as table headers in a view

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I currently have a table in SQL Server that looks something like this:

| Machine | Serial | Date | Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Machine 1 | 12345 | 7/22/2021 | Param 1 | 789 |
| Machine 1 | 12345 | 7/22/2021 | Param 2 | 456 |
| Machine 1 | 67890 | 7/22/2021 | Param 1 | 123 |
| Machine 1 | 67890 | 7/22/2021 | Param 2 | 456 |
| Machine 1 | 34567 | 7/22/2021 | Param 1 | 789 |
| Machine 1 | 34567 | 7/22/2021 | Param 3 | 123 |

I am attempting to create a view that transforms this table into something like this, where each row is defined by it's serial number and the view headers are defined dynamically by the parameters in the 'Parameter' column

| Serial | Machine | Date | Param 1 | Param 2 | Param 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Machine 1 | 7/22/2021 | 789 | 456 |  |
| 67890 | Machine 1 | 7/22/2021 | 123 | 456 |  |
| 34567 | Machine 1 | 7/22/2021 | 789 |  | 123 |

The intention here is that the original table can contain any number of unique parameters and the resultant view will then group by serial number and populate each column with it's respective value based on the parameter it is assigned.

So far I've tried messing with dynamic SQL but have not been able to produce any results. I have done similar things in the past without a dynamic number of parameters in the parameter column. Is something like this even possible on the database side or does this kind of manipulation need to happen on the client side?

Comment: To construct a result set comprised of dynamically generated columns, yes you will need dynamic sql; you won't be able to do this in a view however, it will need a stored procedure. You could have your procedure build a temporary or a permanent table for further use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform this in SQL Server and not the presentation layer, Dynamic SQL would be required

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
From (
        Select Serial
              ,Machine
              ,Date
              ,Parameter
              ,Value
        From #YourTable
     ) src
 Pivot (sum(Value) For [Parameter] in (' + stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Parameter) From  #YourTable Order By 1 For XML Path('') ),1,1,'')  + ') ) pvt'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: I tried this approach but it doesn't like the fact that '#YourTable' in my case is itself a view, not a table and 'Parameter' is a column in that view. Do these objects inside of a dynamic sql statement need to reference an actual table?

Comment: @AddisonWaege Change #YourTable to the actual VIEW name.    The source can be a table or a view, it just doesn't matter.    Just to be clear... dynamic SQL can NOT exists as or within a view.

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning for the 'sum(Value' clause in the query? In my actual database not all the values are of the same datatype so it is throwing an exception on this part.

Comment: @AddisonWaege PIVOT requires an aggregation.  Change sum() to max().  Based on your sample data, I assumed numeric.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use CASE statements on additional columns in your view definition like this:

```
SELECT Serial,
       Machine,
       Date,
       CASE WHEN Parameter = 'Param1' THEN Value ELSE '' END AS Param1,
       CASE WHEN Parameter = 'Param2' THEN Value ELSE '' END AS Param2,
       CASE WHEN Parameter = 'Param3' THEN Value ELSE '' END AS Param3
```

This won't scale well to a large number of parameters, but it should work fine for what you've described here.

If you need this to be dynamic or to accommodate more values you should look into using a PIVOT

Edit: Adding that approach as well, for completeness.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #pivot;

CREATE TABLE #pivot
 (Serial INT,
  Machine VARCHAR(20),
  [Date] DATETIME,
  Parameter VARCHAR(6),
  VALUE INT)

INSERT INTO #pivot
VALUES (12345, 'Machine 1', GETDATE(), 'Param1', 789),
       (12345, 'Machine 1', GETDATE(), 'Param2', 456),
       (67890, 'Machine 1', GETDATE(), 'Param1', 789),
       (67890, 'Machine 1', GETDATE(), 'Param2', 456),
       (34567, 'Machine 1', GETDATE(), 'Param1', 789),
       (34567, 'Machine 1', GETDATE(), 'Param3', 123);

SELECT *
  FROM #pivot;


SELECT Serial, Machine, Date, Param1, Param2, Param3
  FROM #pivot AS p
 PIVOT (
    SUM(p.Value)
    FOR p.Parameter
    IN (Param1, Param2, Param3)
 ) pvt
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15